# C++ if statement notation - Is this equivalent?

Tags: c++, if-statement, syntax

I'm 99% sure this won't work but that remaining 1% is bothering me

```
    int x;

    //is this if statement

    if(x == 1, 5, 7)
    {
    //do something here
    }
    //equivalent to this if statement

    if((x == 1) || (x == 5) || (x == 7))
    {
    //do something here
    }
```

Comment: You could have tried it to see if it works.

Comment: This is the first time I've seen someone try this with commas. They usually try something like `if (x == 1 || 5 || 7)`.

Comment: If you want a fast integer "X is in set Y" operation (where the set Y is known at compile-time), use a `switch` statement, because it gets compiled to a literal hashtable (a branch-table), which is blazingly fast.

Comment: @ Barmar why try when I can get a quick response and find out this way, easy.

Comment: @Dai I have a list of possible values to check for that is quite long and I am trying to see if there is a way to do that without writing an ungodly amount of 'or' conditions or cases if I decide to go with switch. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @ThatGuy _"I have a list of possible values to check for that is quite long"_ Put that list into a `std::array` or `std::vector` and use `std::find_if()`.

Answer (score 5):

No it's totally not equivalent.

```
if(x == 1, 5, 7)
```

calls the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), which will effectively end up in the last value because of `,` has the lowest precedence:

```
if(7)
```

since unfolding with parenthesis should look like

```
if(((x == 1), 5), 7)
```

while

```
if((x == 1) || (x == 2) || (x == 7))
```

checks if `x` equals either `1`, `2` or `7`.

Comment: Comma operator has lowest precedence, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence and http://ideone.com/rxhki1

Comment: @Anedar THX for your tweak, I've gotten unsure meanwhile. Think it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

They are not equal. When you write it like

```
if(x == 1, 5, 7)
    {
    //do something here
    }
```

it basically translates into

```
if(7)
    {
    //do something here
    }
```

which will always be true in case the number in the condition block is a non-zero number.

**Example 1:**

```
int main()
{
    int x=10;
    if(x==1,5,7)
        cout<<"hello"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here, the output is "hello", because 7 is treated as a true boolean variable.

**Example 2:**

```
int main()
    {
        int x=10;
        if(x==1,5,0)
            cout<<"hello"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Here, there is no output because 0 is considered as a false boolean variable.

Comment: You may want to suggest the reason for the expression evaluating to 7, such as the comma operator.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding a faster solution discussed in the comment section of the OP, here's a 'fast' solution:

If you have a large number of *constant comparisons* to perform, a `switch` statement is faster than individual `if(x == 1)` statements as it is compiled to a branch-table (a kind of hashtable directly within program code, giving it `O(1)` lookup), however it's possible that existing compilers will already optimize `if(x==1||x==2||x==3...)` to a branch-table too.

```
bool xIsInSet = false;
switch( x ) {
    case 0: case 1: case 2: case 3:
    case 4: case 5: case 6: case 7: // add a case for each literal comparison
        xIsInSet = true; // no `break` needed, there's only 1 case.
}
if( xIsInSet ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

This can be inlined to a lambda which is invoked immediately to eliminate `xIsInSet`:

```
if( [&x]() -> bool {
    switch(x) { case 0: case 1: case 2: case 3: return true; }
    return false; }()
) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Unfortunately C++11's variadic templates don't let us dynamically add `case` statements, and hacking it using a preprocessor `#define` is possible - if you don't mind using a metaprogramming library. A better alternative might be an inline `#include` of a file generated by your build script. What would be even neater would be a way to somehow `#include` the standard-output from another program (e.g. if we could do `#include '.\generateCasesFor.sh 1 2 5 10 12'`, alas not yet).