# Boost BOOST_PP_SEQ_CAT with custom separator

Tags: c++, boost-preprocessor

Boost's preprocessor library has a neat macro `BOOST_PP_SEQ_CAT` such that:

```
#define MY_SEQUENCE (a)(b)(c)
BOOST_PP_SEQ_CAT(MY_SEQUENCE)
```

becomes:

```
abc
```

In my answer for this question ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/35664207/159145 ) I gave a `switch` statement with many `case` sub-statements as a solution, but lamented the inability to define such a `switch` block via preprocessor macro or variadic template.

I did some more research and found that `BOOST_PP_SEQ_CAT` (defined here: https://github.com/boostorg/preprocessor/blob/develop/include/boost/preprocessor/seq/cat.hpp) ultimately performs concatenation here:

```
#define BOOST_PP_SEQ_CAT_O_I(a, b) a ## b
```

Could it be possible to then allow a macro'ized `switch` statement by modifying this macro?

```
#define BOOST_PP_SEQ_CAT_O_I(ARG_A, ARG_B) case: # ARG_A ## ARG_B
```

e.g.

```
switch(x) {
#define MY_SEQUENCE (1)(5)(7)
BOOST_PP_SEQ_CAT(MY_SEQUENCE)
         return true;
}
```

becomes:

```
switch(x) {
    case 1: case 5: case 7:
        return true;
}
```

Problem is, I can't redefine `BOOST_PP_SEQ_CAT` because it's defined in Boost's own files, and modifying them doesn't seem like the right solution. Is there a way to define my own `BOOST_PP_SEQ_CAT` with the `case:` output without it being redefined by Boost?